# Window tiling (Move-to-{corner,side}) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity, 13.04, shortcut-keys, window-management, tiling

I am trying to figure out how I can change the window tiling shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04. Currently, they are set to `<Ctrl><Alt>numpadn`.

First I tried to check the shortcuts available in keyboard settings in

`System Settings` > `Keyboard` > `Shortcuts` > `Windows`

But it wasn't there. Then I opened `dconf-editor` and navigated
`org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`. There I found the following keys:
`move-to-center`, `move-to-corner-ne`, `move-to-corner-nw`, ...

They are all set to the default value, which is the current working one (e.g. `move-to-corner-nw` => `['<Primary><Alt>KP_Home']`). When I try to change this, nothing happens no matter what shortcut I change to, rather the default value is used. For other keys within the same schema, like `switch-to-workspace-1` or `minimize` the changes set in, they work.

My question is why is values of `move-to-...` keys are ignored? How can I make this shortcut change?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

1. Install the `compizconfig-settings-manager` package.
2. Launch CompizConfig Settings Manager.
3. Navigate to the Grid settings.
4. Set hotkeys to personal preference.

[image: It's the grid plugin in Compiz]

Comment: Thanks, I know Compiz is not a tiling manager, my question was why the shortcuts didn't have effect. I was thinking Compiz would be gone by 13.04, but I checked and its still there, so I downloaded compizconfig-settings-manager and set the shortcuts from there, now it works!

Comment: Can you also edit your answer to reflect the solution, so that I can accept? By the way the Grid plugin comes installed with compiz (which is also preinstalled in 13.04). And the link you gave refers to a MS Windows application used for tiling, it could be a mistake, otherwise misleading.

Comment: The problem I have with this solution is that it not only moves a window, but also resizes it. :-(

Comment: For those used to how it works in Windows 10, this solution does not allow "stepping" across multiple screens, only putting to sides/center (one binding per position).