# How can I setup hotkeys for tiling individual windows in Unity (Ubuntu 12.04)?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I like using combinations of <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd><key></kbd> to tile individual windows. This works in Windows 7+ by default, and in Mac OS X with ShiftIt.app. How can I do this in Ubuntu Precise 12.04?

Answer (score 9):

You can tile windows to the left and right halves of the screen using <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> respectively. Also, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> maximizes the window, while <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> minimizes/restores it.

You can also tile windows to the corners of the screen (bottom right, bottom left, etc.) using the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad</kbd>, where the numpad number roughly corresponds to the position you want the window to be. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad 1</kbd> will move the window to the bottom left corner.
<sub>**(Source: [Window tiling (Move-to-{corner,side}) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/289871/52726))**</sub>

---

### Customize these shortcuts

To customize maximizing (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) and minimizing (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>) windows, simply go to your **Systems Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** tab → **Windows** and look for *Maximize Window* and *Restore Window*.

[image]
[image]
[image]

To customize tiling to the left (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>) and right (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>), you'll need to install [CompizConfig Settings Manager [image: Install ccsm]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ccsm). Once you have it installed, open it up, and search for **Grid** in the Filter box, and click on it. Find *Put Left* and *Put Right* and edit them accordingly.
<sub>**(Source: [Window tiling (Move-to-{corner,side}) shortcuts in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/289871/52726))**</sub>

[image]

---

### Example screenshots of default tiling:

Window opened normally:

[image]

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>:

[image]

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>:

[image]

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How could I customize these keys?

Comment: @apennebaker I've edited my answer.